# Energy of a scalar field in curved spacetime

Tags: energy, black-holes, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am confused about the expression for energy of a scalar field in a spherical shell in S-dS spacetime that appears in eq. (2.4) of the article `Gravitational Interactions of Finite Thickness Global Topological Defects with Black Holes' (https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.08098). I am describing the issue below.

The background metric $g_{ab}$ is spherically symmetric and static, with
$$ds^2 = f(r)dt^2 - \frac{1}{f(r)}dr^2 -r^2(d\theta^2+sin^2 \theta d\varphi^2).$$
Let there be a complex scalar field with an action
$$S=\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \left(g^{ab}\nabla_a \Phi \nabla_b \Phi -V(\Phi)\right).$$
Here, as usual, $g=det(g_{ab})$. The energy density $\rho$ of the field that an observer moving with a four velocity $U$ normalised to $g(U,U)=1$ measures is,
$$\rho=T_{ab}U^a U^b = \frac{T_{00}}{g_{00}}=T^0_0$$.
Now, the energy in a spherical shell of radius r lying between $r_1\leq r \geq r_2$ is,
$$ E = \int d^3x \sqrt{|h|} \rho, $$
where $h_{\mu\nu}$ is the metric induced by $g_{ab}$ on the spatial hypersurface at a constant time. Simply, it is the spatial part of $g_{ab}$. (Latin indices $a,b=0,1,2,3$ while Greek indices $\mu,\nu=1,2,3$.) $|h|=|det (h_{\mu\nu})|=\frac{r^4 sin^2 \theta}{f(r)}$. Thus,
$$ E = 4 \pi \int dr \frac{1}{\sqrt{f(r)}}r^2 \rho. $$
The field has been assumed to be static and spherically symmetric, though it is not relevant for this question.

In the paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.08098), in eq. (2.4), the authors have used $\sqrt{-g}$ in place of $\sqrt{-h}$ and hence, the results are different. I expect a factor of $1/\sqrt{f(r)}$ which is absent there.

My question is, is there anything wrong in the way I have defined the integral for energy? Any insight will be very valuable. Thank you.

Comment: The factor does not show up in the article you cite.  Note, equation 4.7.  I assume they mean $h$ when they write down $g$

Comment: Yes, but then the factor of $1/\sqrt{f}$ should appear, isn't it?