# Energy and momenta of a field on a curved manifold

Tags: spacetime, momentum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In a curved spacetime with metric $g$, let us have a complex scalar field $\Phi$. The stress energy momentum tensor of the field is defined as,
$$T_{ab} := \frac{-2}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta S_\Phi}{\delta g^{ab}}.$$
Here, $S_\Phi$ is the action describing the field. Given this, I am confused about how we define the energy and momentum of the field. For example, the energy density that an observer moving with 4-velocity $u$ measures is,
$$\rho= T_{ab}u^au^b.$$
I would expect the total energy measured by him to be,
$$E=\int_\Sigma d^3x \sqrt{h} \rho,$$
where $\Sigma$ is the spatial slice orthogonal to $u$ and $h$ is the 3-metric on this spatial section. However, this is not how it is defined usually.

The standard definition of the momentum 4-vector is,
$$P^a = \int d^3x \sqrt{-g} T_0^{a},$$
with $E=P^0$. Can you help me understand how one can logically arrive at the correct way of defining the momentum 4-vector on a curved manifold? Especially, I want to know why $\sqrt{-g}$ appears in the integral instead of $\sqrt{h}$. Thank you!

N.B.: This question is related to my previous question [Energy of a scalar field in curved spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769269/)  , but I have made it more general.

Answer (score 2):

First of all it is convinient to perform such a calculation in a comoving reference frame, in which the components of the stress energy tensor have a well defined physical meaning:

- $T_{00}$ is the energy density [*]
- $T_{0i} = T_{i0}$ is the flux of energy through the $x^i$ surface, or equivalently the flux of the $i$ component of linear momentum through the $x^0$ surface [**]
- $T_{ij}$ are the fluxes of the $i$ components of linear momentum through the $x^j$ surfaces.

We know that for every tensor holds:

$$T^{\mu \nu}_{\;\;;\nu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}(T^{\mu \nu}\sqrt{-g})$$

Since $T^{\mu \nu}_{\;\;;\nu} = 0$ in general relativity, then

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}(T^{\mu \nu}\sqrt{-g}) = 0$$

Getting rid of the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}$ the above equation becomes:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}(T^{\mu \nu}\sqrt{-g}) = 0$$

Given a spacelike hypersurface $\Sigma = V: x^0 = const$ we can integrate the above espression:

$$\int_{\Sigma} d^3V\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}(T^{\mu \nu}\sqrt{-g}) = 0$$

Here $d^3V$ is the 3D volume element in comoving coordinates, which is the invariant volume form of $\Sigma$.

Splitting the sum into time + space components then you have:

$$\int_{\Sigma} d^3V\frac{\partial}{\partial x^0}(T^{\mu 0}\sqrt{-g}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(T^{\mu i}\sqrt{-g}) = 0$$

So

$$\int_{\Sigma} d^3V \frac{\partial}{\partial x^0}(T^{\mu 0}\sqrt{-g}) = -\int_{\Sigma} d^3V \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(T^{\mu i}\sqrt{-g})$$

You can take the partial time derivate out of the integral and rewrite the RHS with the divergence theorem:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^0}\int_{\Sigma} d^3V (T^{\mu 0}\sqrt{-g}) = -\int_{\partial \Sigma} d^2S_i (T^{\mu i}\sqrt{-g})$$

Assuming $T^{\mu i}$ is zero at the boundary at infinity you obtain:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^0}\int_{\Sigma} d^3V (T^{\mu 0}\sqrt{-g}) = 0$$

Which means that:

$$\int_{\Sigma} d^3V (T^{\mu 0}\sqrt{-g}) = const := P^{\mu}$$

We identify the 4 constants with the four momentum because the same constants appear when doing the same procedure with Killing vectors associated to spacetime translations, so due to Noether theorems they are identified with the 4-momentum.
If such a simmetry doesn't exist the expression above is still valid but the $P^\mu$ constants have a more tricky meaning than that of the TOTAL 4-momentum.

Note: $P^\mu$ does not depend on the spatial position since it is integrated: it is not the 4-momentum vector but the total 4-momentum of all of the spacetime geometry.

In such a case the defining equation is:

$$\int_{\Sigma} d^3V (\xi_\mu T^{\mu 0}\sqrt{-g}) = const$$

Where

$$\xi_\mu ^{(0)} = \delta ^0 _\mu$$

for time translations and

$$\xi_\mu ^{(i)} = \delta ^i _\mu$$

for the 3 spacial translations.

Finally, the reasons why $\sqrt{-g}\;$ appears is not due to integration but due to the equation defining the covariant 4-divergence of tensors. In fact, you could define a tensor density as:

$$\mathfrak{T}^{\mu \nu} = T^{\mu \nu}\sqrt{-g}$$

And work with this, to eliminate the square root of the determinant from your integral equation as:

$$\int_{\Sigma} d^3V (\xi_\mu \mathfrak{T}^{\mu 0}) = const$$

---

[*] A density can be interpreted as a flux through the $x^0$ surface, so the $T_{00}$ is the flux through $x^0$ of the zero component of the 4-momentum: the energy density

[**] As stated above, the flux through $x^0$ is a density, so the flux of spacial linear momentum through $x^0$ is just the 3-momentum density

Comment: There are various issues with this answer. For example, according to this argument, $\partial_0 P^\mu = 0$ in any spacetime, which is not true.

Comment: How do you justify the fact that you have chosen a non-invariant integration measure $d^3V$?

Comment: If you define $P^\mu$ as the integral expression above then it IS true that $\partial_0 P^\mu =0$, you literally have your proof above

Comment: I never said i didn't choose a non-invariant measure. I said that $d^3 V$ your volume form in comoving coordinates. A volume form it's always an invariant 3-form, since in a 3D orienteed manifold there exist only one volume form. It's expression coordinate-wise depends on your comoving coordinates choice

Comment: Since $\Sigma$ is a 3 dimensional Riemannian manifold you integrate over the manifold volume 3-form

Comment: There is no speciality of comoving coordinates. The volume form needs to have the determinant of the appropriate metric, otherwise it is not invariant under change of coordinates.

Comment: Ok, the wording of that part of your answer wasn't clear to me. My bad. So, I have removed the comment where I said the argument is wrong. However, if you explicitly write your $d^3V$ explicitly in any non-orthonormal coordinate system, the objection to integration measure will become clear to you. If there is anything more to discuss, please move this discussion to chat.

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker, so i guess my wording is a bit unclear sometimes. I don't understand what is the problem with $d^3V$, i'll move it to chat to understand it better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148243/discussion-between-lolloboldo-and-damaihati).

Comment: If you can please edit the answer, I can remove the down vote.

Comment: Edited to clarify the volume and $P^\mu$ statements